# How create a table df_toLatex() on multiple pages ? PyLatex - Pandas - Python

Tags: longtable, pylatex

I would like to generate a report for a specific process with a long dataframe on multiple pages. But when I try to generate it, the table is only on a single page and not whole. I try the package `longtable` but it's not working.

Here my currently code (UPDATED):

```
import pandas as pd
import pylatex as pl

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(256),y=['same']*256))

doc = pl.Document()

doc.packages.append(pl.Package('booktabs'))
doc.packages.append(pl.Package('longtable'))

with doc.create(pl.Section('Table: Global Faults ')):
    with doc.create(pl.Table(position='htbp')) as table:
        table.add_caption('Five first')
        table.append(pl.Command('centering'))
        table.append(pl.NoEscape(df.to_latex(longtable=True)))


doc.generate_pdf(filepath=f'Global_Fault', clean_tex=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.StackExchange! Please be sure to make your example compilable -- e.g. adding `import pylatex as pl; import pandas as pd; df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(256),y=['same']*256));` (newlines as `;` since comments here are inline).

Comment: You may find [this example](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/longtable.html) helpful

Comment: @jessexknight thanks for your comments, I updated my code. For the example, I already work in this example, I broke my head on it several hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `longtable` environment is not supposed to be used inside of a `table` environment. The caption should be provided as an argument to `df.to_latex`. Centering is default.

MWE:

```python
import pandas as pd
import pylatex as pl

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(256),y=['same']*256))

doc = pl.Document()

doc.packages.append(pl.Package('booktabs'))
doc.packages.append(pl.Package('longtable'))

with doc.create(pl.Section('Table: Global Faults ')):
    doc.append(pl.NoEscape(df.to_latex(longtable=True,caption='Five first')))

doc.generate_pdf(filepath=f'Global_Fault', clean_tex=False)
```

Generated LaTeX:

```
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\section{Table: Global Faults }%
\label{sec:TableGlobalFaults}%
\begin{longtable}{lrl}
\caption{Five first}\\
\toprule
{} &    x &     y \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\
\midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
0   &    0 &  same \\
1   &    1 &  same \\
% etc.
```

Result:

[image]

[...]

[image]

Comment: Ok I understand my error. I wanted to use an implementation that I had already used a few weeks ago but had not been faced with the longtable case ... Thanks a lot for the help !